# How to override fields_view_get of TransientModel in odoo 10?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I already did it and in older odoo version this way it worked!
Cant see this 'kecske' signal in the log file. No error message. If I wrote some code before super, it hasn't any effect.

Any idea? Is it the right way?

```py
class DemoWizard(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'demo.wizard'

    name = fields.Char(string='Name')

    @api.model
    def fields_view_get(self, view_id=None, view_type='form', toolbar=False, submenu=False):
        log = logging.getLogger('demo.wizard.fields_view_get()')
        log.debug('kecske')
        return super(DemoWizard,self).fields_view_get(view_id, view_type, toolbar, submenu)
```

Comment: I am going to post an example from the Odoo10 source code. I have not tested it. It looks very close to what you have. The only difference that I can see is that in Odoo's call to super() they use keyword arguments and not positional arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is from Odoo10 source. The file is found in the anonymization addon. `odoo/addons/anonymization/wizard/anonymize_wizard.py`. Notice the call to super() and the use of keyword arguments as apposed to positional arguments.

Other than that your code looks correct.

In your example you initialised logging using a different technique. Try initialising your logger as follows.

```
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
log.info("My Log Message")
```

or for debug.

```
log.debug("My debug message")
```

`info,debug,warning,error` can be used to log different degrees of severity of log messages.

```
@api.model
def fields_view_get(self, view_id=None, view_type='form', toolbar=False, submenu=False):
    state = self.env['ir.model.fields.anonymization']._get_global_state()
    step = self.env.context.get('step', 'new_window')
    res = super(IrModelFieldsAnonymizeWizard, self).fields_view_get(view_id=view_id, view_type=view_type, toolbar=toolbar, submenu=submenu)
    eview = etree.fromstring(res['arch'])
    placeholder = eview.xpath("group[@name='placeholder1']")
    if len(placeholder):
        placeholder = placeholder[0]
        if step == 'new_window' and state == 'clear':
            # clicked in the menu and the fields are not anonymized: warn the admin that backuping the db is very important
            placeholder.addnext(etree.Element('field', {'name': 'msg', 'colspan': '4', 'nolabel': '1'}))
            placeholder.addnext(etree.Element('newline'))
            placeholder.addnext(etree.Element('label', {'string': 'Warning'}))
            eview.remove(placeholder)
        elif step == 'new_window' and state == 'anonymized':
            # clicked in the menu and the fields are already anonymized
            placeholder.addnext(etree.Element('newline'))
            placeholder.addnext(etree.Element('field', {'name': 'file_import', 'required': "1"}))
            placeholder.addnext(etree.Element('label', {'string': 'Anonymization file'}))
            eview.remove(placeholder)
        elif step == 'just_anonymized':
            # we just ran the anonymization process, we need the file export field
            placeholder.addnext(etree.Element('newline'))
            placeholder.addnext(etree.Element('field', {'name': 'file_export'}))
            # we need to remove the button:
            buttons = eview.xpath("button")
            for button in buttons:
                eview.remove(button)
            # and add a message:
            placeholder.addnext(etree.Element('field', {'name': 'msg', 'colspan': '4', 'nolabel': '1'}))
            placeholder.addnext(etree.Element('newline'))
            placeholder.addnext(etree.Element('label', {'string': 'Result'}))
            # remove the placeholer:
            eview.remove(placeholder)
        elif step == 'just_desanonymized':
            # we just reversed the anonymization process, we don't need any field
            # we need to remove the button
            buttons = eview.xpath("button")
            for button in buttons:
                eview.remove(button)
            # and add a message
            placeholder.addnext(etree.Element('field', {'name': 'msg', 'colspan': '4', 'nolabel': '1'}))
            placeholder.addnext(etree.Element('newline'))
            placeholder.addnext(etree.Element('label', {'string': 'Result'}))
            # remove the placeholer:
            eview.remove(placeholder)
        else:
            raise UserError(_("The database anonymization is currently in an unstable state. Some fields are anonymized,"
                              " while some fields are not anonymized. You should try to solve this problem before trying to do anything else."))
        res['arch'] = etree.tostring(eview)
    return res
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it is doesn't solve my problem. The log still doesn't contain what I write before return, as I said.
And this two call method are same. But thank you your helping intentioned answer.

Comment: With regards to you logger. Normally I see a logger initialised like this. `log = logging.getLogger(__name__)` can you try that and see if your logging appears?

Comment: Also, in your conf or server startup script are you logging at debug level? Verify that you are logging at the level your code is outputting logs for. If your start script is  using `info` then you should use `log.info('Hello World')`

Comment: Uuuuh you are right when you said `getLogger(__name__)`! :O (the log level was correct) In older version this getLogger works well. Shame on me. But when I call a function like `self.myFunction()`, and that method contains `getLogger(__name__)` and log.debug('kamion') on the top of method, it still doesn't in log file.

Comment: Try using info level logging. `log.info('Hello')` not sure why this is not working for you.

Comment: Doesn't work, but when I copy the method code to the fields_view_get, it is worked...what the hell is that? But the original problem was solved. So if you edit answer, then I will take an 'accept' mark to yours. And thank you very mach again!

Comment: What do you mean by copy the method code to the fields_view_get? I am not sure if I know how to edit my answer to be correct.

Comment: What should I change?

Comment: I copied the code of `self.myFunction()` to fields_view_get function, and its worked. But when I just called that function, it didn't happen.
The key idea of the solving was your comment to the logger.

Comment: I will add the logging notes to my answer. Thank you very much. I am glad your are moving on in your project now. Have a great day!